# Regular expression for secret code

Tags: regex

I've created one text field which accepts the product code.
I have tried many ways and got disappointed.
The product code is having some validations like follows,

```
Product code :315299AZ

1.First 2 digits ranges from[01-31].,should not contain 00.
2.Second 2 digits ranges from [01-52]., should not contain 00.
3.Third 2 digits ranges from [00-99].
4.Last 2 are optional. But should accept only alphabets. Should not accepts numbers.
```

Please someone help me to get out of it.

Comment: How optional are the last 2 characters?  Must there be 2, or is only one acceptable?  Does capitalization matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex :

```
(?!00)(([0-2][0-9])|31|30)(?!00)(([0-4][0-9])|51|50|52)(\d{2})([a-zA-Z]{2})?
```

`(?!00)` is a negative look-ahead that doesn't allows `00`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OKnZKfurbaCeetvo)

Comment: It validates fine. but the alphabets at the last 2 places are optional. If  I am not entered the alphabets at the end it does not match...

Comment: @karthik So you can simply put the last part within a capture group and use `?` token to make it optional! ;) checkout the edit!

Comment: @karthik Welcome, so what about accepting my answer? ;)

Comment: now i need another help like the same. Shall i ask?

Comment: @karthik Sure but i thinks its better to ask it as another question!in that case you may get better and various answer!

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
((0[1-9])|([1-2]\d)|(3[0-1]))((0[1-9])|([1-4]\d)|(5[0-2]))\d{2}([a-zA-Z]{2})?
```

If you don't like look-aheads.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not the spirit, but any sensible language supporting regular expressions should allow you to access groups, hence do something along these lines (pseudocode follows):

```
if product_code matches /^(\d\d)(\d\d)\d\d([a-zA-Z]{2})?$/ {
    assert 1 <= int($1) <= 31 // validate first group
    assert 1 <= int($2) <= 52 // validate second group
}
```

Bonus: you can actually read it.

(This is assuming the last optional group contains either two or zero characters. If one character is acceptable, you can replace it with `[a-zA-Z]{0,2}`)